Bits and bytes shifts C++
I have a rather interesting task. I need to perform a bit shift with a cutout of the bits. That is, I have a binary .bin file. The first 16 bytes must be skipped, the byte numbering starts from 0, then cut 3 bits from 17 bytes, 140 141 and 142 bits. and shift the entire sequence by these 3 bits, Then skip 32 bytes, and again cut 3 bits from the byte, and shift the sequence again. I don't understand a little bit how to make a shift when you need to shift more than 1 byte already.The condition also stated that the program should be time-efficient. In less than a minute, you need to process a file with about 50 million bytes. Accordingly, there are no nested loops and the like.
Here is the sample code that I got, I think I'm going in the right direction, but I don't understand just what to do to shift more than 1 byte correctly.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>


std::vector<uint8_t> Shift(std::vector<uint8_t>& src, int val, bool left) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> res(src.size());
    int byteShift = val >> 3;
    uint8_t mask = ~(0b00001110);
    if (byteShift >= src.size())
        return res;
    val = 3;
    res.insert(res.begin(), src.begin(), src.begin() + 17); // Copy the first 17 bytes unchanged
    int j = 1;
    for (size_t i = 17; i < src.size()-j; i++) {
        if ((i - 16) % 32 == 0 && i != 17) {
            res[i + j] = static_cast<uint8_t>(((src[i + j] &= mask)>>3) | (src[i + j + 1] << 5));

            res[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(((src[i] >> val) | (res[i + j] << 8 - val)));

            switch (val)
            {
            case 1: 
                val = 4;
                break;
            case 2:
                val = 5;
                break;
            case 3:
                val = 6;
                break;
            case 4:
                val = 7;
                break;
            case 5:
                val = 8;
                break;
            case 6:
                val = 1;
                j++;
                break;
            case 7: 
                val = 2;
                j++;
                break;
            case 8:
                val = 3;
                j++;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            res[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>((src[i] >> val) | (src[i + j] << (8 - val)));
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    const std::string inputFileName = "F:/C++ Progect/ConsoleApplication5/ConsoleApplication5/x64/Debug/0_1.bin";
    const std::string outputFileName = "output.bin";
    const int shiftValue = 3;
    const bool shiftLeft = false; // Change to false for right shift

    try {
        std::ifstream inputFile(inputFileName, std::ios::binary);
        if (!inputFile)
            throw std::runtime_error("The input file could not be opened.");

        inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::streampos fileSize = inputFile.tellg();
        inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        std::vector<uint8_t> inputData(fileSize);
        inputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(inputData.data()), fileSize);

        std::vector<uint8_t> shiftedData = Shift(inputData, shiftValue, shiftLeft);

        std::ofstream outputFile(outputFileName, std::ios::binary);
        if (!outputFile)
            throw std::runtime_error("The output file could not be created.");

        outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(shiftedData.data()), shiftedData.size());

        std::cout << "The shift was completed successfully." << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hC4kwNwTLT9tZG6uFiHy8VT-V_8zPZGh?usp=sharing
I attach a link to google drive with the source file, and with the one that should turn out, 0_1 is the source, 1_1 is the result of the program

First read all the data you need into a single (unsigned) byte buffer. Then as you know which bits (in which bytes) you need, extract them one by one, using normal sequential statements, and store in a std::bitfield. From that you can get the possible value as a plain integer.

What is expected result - some extracted bits (packed together)  or the rest bits (long array) ? Could you show exact problem description?

Well, I described the work of the algorithm above, every 32 bytes after 17 we cut out 3 bits, and shift all the bytes by these 3 bits, somehow, at the output you need to get the same bin file, but from which about 5 000 000 bits will be cut in this way. That is, in 17 bytes we cut out 3 bits, shift by 3 bits, then in 32 + 17 we cut out 3 more bits, shift by 6 bits, in 32+32+17 We cut out 3 more bits, the shift is already 9 bits, etc.

This answer was first posted: 09/04/2024
When you're writing bits starting with "0b", try writing them in 8/16/32/64 bits in length and not 3, 4 or 5 as it may not be seen as a 3-bit variable, but as a 8/16/32/64 bit variable. It may see 0b111 either as 0b11100000 or 0b00011111.
Here is a demonstration of how bitshifting works, though you might find it irrelevant.
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset <8> x;
    cout << "Bitshifting 00000001 right to left" << endl;
    cout << "Nr of Shifts |  Result" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        x = (0 | (0b00000001 << i));
        cout << i << "            | " << x << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Bitshifting 00000001 left to right" << endl;
    cout << "Nr of Shifts |  Result" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        x = (0 | (0b00000001 >> i));
        cout << i << "            | " << x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

EDIT 1: This edit is posted 09/04/2024
Here is a more or less generic function that lets you use an array of bytes to shift. This function shifts the array as if it was ONE VARIABLE of 8*N bits long, where N is the number of bytes in the array.
The function below does the following:

In a forloop of array size number of times:

Shift the byte a user defined number of bits to the left. The result of this shift is called x1.

Shift the next byte (if it exists) in the array 8 - ("user defined number of bits" % 8) and logic or the resulting shift with x1.




Code for the function:
void shift_Array_of_bytes(uint8_t byte[], unsigned int arraySize, uint32_t nrOfBitShifts) {
    unsigned int bytesShifted = floor(nrOfBitShifts / 8);
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < arraySize; index++) {
        if (index + bytesShifted >= arraySize - 1)
            byte[index] = (byte[index + bytesShifted] << (nrOfBitShifts - bytesShifted * 8));
        else if (index + bytesShifted < arraySize - 1)
            byte[index] = (byte[index + bytesShifted] << (nrOfBitShifts - bytesShifted * 8)) | (byte[index + bytesShifted + 1] >> (8 - (nrOfBitShifts % 8)));
        }

    if(bytesShifted > 0) {
        for (unsigned int index1 = 0; index1 < bytesShifted; index1++) {
            byte[arraySize - 1 - index1] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Here is the test code for the function:
#include<cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    
    bitset<8> x;
    uint8_t data[] = { 5,1,6};
    int dataSize = 3;

    cout << "\n\n" << "<-- before bitshifting -->  ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        x = data[i];
        cout << x;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        x = data[i];
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    shift_Array_of_bytes(data, dataSize, 5);

    cout << "\n\n" << "<-- after bitshifting -->  ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        x = data[i];
        cout << x;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        x = data[i];
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

you can crosscheck the results of the function with this your windows calculator using programmer calculator.

Yes, indeed, such a record will look better.
In my case, uint8_t mask = ~(0b00001110), but it did not make a difference to me, since the mask in the entry uint8_t mask = ~(0b111 << 1); was considered correct

I have just edited this answer we are currently commenting on. I have made a function that can shift more than 8-bits, and does it across several bytes at a time.  you may need to edit the function to account for possible array overflow and change the input data type to your liking. @ЛеонидИльин
